# How to make D3 axis label and ticks conditional for date range from a day to some years?

Tags: javascript, svg, d3.js

I have a d3 graph with date range for axis can be from a day to 5 years. I have set the tick format based on the difference between two selected dates and have set fixed ticks to 7.

here is my code:

```
xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(xRange)
    .orient("bottom")
    .tickFormat(function(d, i) {
        var timeFormatter = d3.time.format(getXTimeFormat(currentDateExtents[0], currentDateExtents[1], d,      i));
                return timeFormatter((new Date(d)));
   })
   .ticks(7)
```

I have also set, unique format for each start date, for example: 10Jun 4am 7am ..10am 11Jun 4am...
the time at origin always starts at 12 am midnight, and the first tick after origin is generated which dispalys 10Jun **but the time at ticks 10jun or 11jun is something like 1am which seems to be unusual.**

**How to make d3 to starts the axis at origin 10jun and then each subsequest ticks to be some time value, but when starting the next day, make this tick time to be 12 am.**

This works when selecting one day or more than 7 days or 6.
but anything between these two, the ticks not starting from midnight, if i select 2 or 3 days.

All of the issues can be solved if d3 supports

```
.ticks(function(){return d3.time.hours/days/months;},function(){return tickInterval;)).
```

any suggestion will be appreciated. 
Thanks

Comment: Are you looking for a [custom multi-scale time format](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/4149176)?

Comment: yes, d3.time.format.multi, i tries to use without success. error is undefined when using this

Comment: Can you give a complete example when you're getting this error please?